# Merging with partial string match in Python like Excel VLOOKUP

Tags: python, pandas, replace, merge, left-join

I have two data sets: Sales(for company names) & Marketing(for contacts and company names). I want to match the company names in my marketing data set with the company names in my sales data set even if (especially if) there are partial matches.

Sample Data

```
sales_df = pd.DataFrame({'CompanyName': ['EDF', 'EDF Business', 'L'Oreal France', 'L'oreal Produits De Luxe Belgilux - Be'],        

marketing_df = pd.DataFrame({'ContactName': ['Eddie', 'Antoine', 'Tracy', 'Iria'],
                'Email': ['eddie@edf.fr', 'antoine.g@edf.fr', 'tracy@us.loreal.com', 'iria@loreal.com'],
                'CompanyName': ['EDF', 'EDF', 'L'Oréal', 'L’Oreal Produit Luxe France''],
                'Industry': ['Energy', 'Energy', 'CPG', 'CPG']})
```

Ultimately, I am going for a solution that behaves like a VLOOKUP in Excel, where I return the rows of my marketing data set that match/partially match the company name in my sales data set. This way I have company and contact level (email address & contact name) data that I can use to know which contacts in my marketing data set belong to companies in my sales data set.

Desired result

```
    ContactName Email               CompanyName    Industry
0   Eddie       eddie@edf.fr        edf            Energy
1   Antoine     antoine.g@edf.fr    edf            Energy
2   Tracy       tracy@us.loreal.com loreal...      CPG
3   Iria        iria@loreal.com     loreal...      Energy
```

Basically, I want to keep all the contact-level data as long as the contact belongs to a company from my sales data set.

Here, I clean my data.

```
# import Pandas
import pandas as pd

# Convert spreadsheets into data frames
marketing_df = pd.read_csv('/Users/me/Desktop/Project Data/Country_MKTG_data.csv')
sales_df = pd.read_csv('/Users/me/Desktop/Project Data/Country_Sales_data.csv')

# Display all rows & drop null values in company name columns  
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
marketing_df['CompanyMKTG'] = marketing_df['CompanyMKTG'].dropna()
sales_df['CompanySales'] = sales_df['CompanySales'].dropna()

# Make all company names lower case   
sales_df['CompanySales'] = sales_df['CompanySales'].str.lower()
marketing_df['CompanyMKTG'] = marketing_df['CompanyMKTG'].str.lower()

# Eliminate unwanted characters & words    
bad_characters = ['-', ',', '.', '?', '~', '/', 'france', 'ltd', 'uk', 'sa', 'sas', 'the', 'spain', 'japan', 'usa', 'la', 'le', 'de']

for element in bad_characters:
     marketing_df['CompanyMKTG'] = marketing_df['CompanyMKTG'].str.replace(element, '', case=False)
     sales_df['CompanySales'] = sales_df['CompanySales'].str.replace(element, '', case=False)

# Clean white space  
marketing_df['CompanyMKTG'] = marketing_df['CompanyMKTG'].str.rstrip().str.replace(' ', '')
sales_df['CompanySales'] = sales_df['CompanySales'].str.rstrip().str.replace(' ', '')
```

The problem is that after cleaning the data, I am having trouble merging my dataframes using partial string matching. I have tried many different methods: merging, joining, using difflib for percentage matching, converting to sets and finding the intersection of both sets.

My latest solution is to check whether company names in both my data sets are substrings of each other to then replace the company names in my marketing data set with the names in my sales data set. This way I can export a new dataframe with my marketing contacts that only belong to companies in my sales data set.

```
# Replace company names in MKTG data set
real_comp = sales_df['CompanySales'].tolist()

for i in marketing_df:
      if i['CompanyMKTG'].isin(real_comp):
        if i['CompanyMKTG'].issubstring(real_comp[real_comp.get_index(i['CompanySales'])]):
          if real_comp[real_comp.get_index(i['CompanySales'])].issubstring((i['CompanyMKTG'])):
            marketing_df['CompanyMKTG'].replace(real_comp, inplace=True)
            i['CompanySales'] = real_comp[real_comp.get_index(i['CompanyMKTG'])]
```

BUT I keep getting TypeError: string indices must be integers

Or simply returning the rows that have a partial string match using pd.series.apply

```
def get_match(x):
   return marketing_df.loc[marketing_df['CompanyMKTG'].str.contains(x, na=False), 'EmailAddress'].iloc[0]

sales_df['Match'] = sales_df['CompanySales'].apply(get_match)
print(sales_df)
```

But this way I get IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: It would be good if you can post some sample data of the two dataframes and the expected result.

Comment: @Mohammad I added some sample data. I hope this provides useful context.

Comment: I'm not sure what the desired result is. For e.g you seem to have two companies having the name EDF in them. How are you suggesting to merge theae with the other dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

the reason that you get the error is that when you use for loop to interate through the DF you get the names of the Columns in string format that's is why the i['CompanyMKTG'] is throwing error.

To avoid this error you can use the iterrows method to iterate through the rows.

```
for index , row in marketing_df.iterrows()
```

As you want to extract the data from marketing data sets by comparing the sales data set company names. You may use below, after doing all cleansing process as you did.

```
marketing_df[marketing_df['CompanyMKTG'].isin(sales_df)]
```

Note that there is no method as issubstring for a Dataframe or a series. Please refer the DOC-->https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html

Also Using isin() method in IF statement will throw exception/error as the o/p is ambigous. If you want to use multiple condition you may use the below to validate the condition and print the resultant marketing data set.

```
r=[]
for i, row in marketing_df.iterrows():
    if row['CompanyMKTG'] in str(sales_df['CompanyMKTG']):
        r.append(row['CompanyMKTG'])
marketing_df[marketing_df['CompanyMKTG'].isin(r)]
```